# How to update value attribute using periodicalupdater in prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

How to update value attribute using periodicalupdater in prototype?

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('content', '/content/',
{
    method: 'post',
    frequency: 5,
});
```

This updates text inside element.. I want to update value attribute.. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the source, it seems [`Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/) passes it's options directly to an [`Ajax.Updater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/), which in turn supports an `insertion` option.  The documentation says `insertion` can be a string but it leaves out a useful detail, it [may be a function](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/d9411e5/src/prototype/ajax/updater.js#L122).

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('content', '/content/',
{
    method: 'post',
    frequency: 5,
    insertion: Form.Element.setValue
});
```

This isn't tested but I believe the default [`Element.insert`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/insert/) can be replaced with [`Form.Element.setValue`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/setValue/) since the arguments are in identical order

---

**Update:** Prototype.js is older than HTML5 so does not support `<progress>` elements.  `Form.Element.setValue()` works out which method to use by an element's tag name and it has no method for `progress`, which is why the above fails.  Instead we can write our own function to take the place of `Form.Element.setValue`:

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('content', '/content/',
{
    method: 'post',
    frequency: 5,
    insertion: function (progress, value) {
        progress.value = value;
        if (value >= progress.max) throw $break;
    }
});
```

Comment: very good thinking but it didn't work.. I guess because the insertion option takes a String object not an Element or a Form object..

Comment: I was so sure that I decided to test it after all, please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/779ttdyr/1/) as proof.  What do you see when it doesn't work?  Is there an error in the browser's console?

Comment: wow.. it actually worked .. the problem is i was trying it in a HTML5 progressbar element. when I replaced it with an input element it worked.. what could be the reason of that?!

Comment: A progress bar element is an interesting twist, I experimented with it in [a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxnuxbm6/1/) and found a workaround.

Comment: On reflection I made a mistake by starting with the assumption you meant to use a form element.  I should have read your question more literally.